# Solution to complicated expression with nested radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

I'm looking to solve a fairly complex expression for $x$ which I will give below:

$$x^2-2b=c\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+a(x)}\right)-x\sqrt{x^2+a(x)}.$$

Here $b$ and $c$ are constants and $a(x)=2\sqrt{b-x^2}$. This expression is the result of solving a nonlinear system of 3 equations ($x$ is one of the unknowns in the system), and we know that $x>0$ and $b>0$. I have been unable to make any progress beyond this point (it already wasn't easy to get here). I would appreciate any tips on how to proceed in solving this equation for $x$. I know the result is quite complicated (but still tractable), so I would just like some assistance on what methods to try.

**EDIT**: I will provide the system this equation came from, in the event that there is a better way to generate an equation for $x$. The system is

$$-2x_2+\nu x_1+x_1^2+x_2^2=0$$
$$-x_3+\nu x_2+(x_1+x_3)x_2=\alpha\nu$$
$$\nu x_3+x_2^2+x_3^2=0$$

This should be approximately correct, since I had nondimensionalized at a later point in my derivations. The constants are then $b=\nu^2/4$ and $c=\alpha-1/2$ and

$$x=\sqrt{b-x_2^2}$$

It is desired to solve for $x_2$, since the final result I am looking for only depends on that unknown. I generated the equation for $x$ by solving the first and third equations for $x_3(x_2)$ and $x_1(x_2)$ and substituting into the second equation.

**EDIT 2:** I should also add there's a bit of physical insight that goes into dropping possible solutions from quadratics. Essentially, if $x_2=0$ we expect $x_1=x_3=0$ as well. This doesn't satisfy the system because I have assumed $x_2\neq0$ in my nondimensionalization ($\nu\to\infty$ for $x_2\to0$).

Comment: What's the original system?

Comment: The tedious, but straightforward thing to do is to isolate the outer radical, which you can do, square to eliminate it, rearrange and square again.

Comment: I've rearranged it into the cubic $(a+4c)x^3+(2ac+4b)x^2+(ac^2-4bc)x-4b^2=0$. Unless I made a mistake, the roots are quite heinous (according to Mathematica).

Comment: @ElliotG $a$ is also a function of $x$

Comment: Ah then completely disregard.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have provided the system the equation came from. Perhaps there is another way to solve for $x_2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a polynomial equation:
$$x^2-2b=cx-(c+x)\sqrt{x^2+a(x)}\\x^2-cx-2b=-(c+x)\sqrt{x^2+a(x)}$$
Now you square both sides (make sure you check the solution because of this), so $$(x^2-cx-2b)^2=(c+x)^2(x^2+a(x))\\\frac{(x^2-cx-2b)^2}{(c+x)^2}=x^2+a(x)=x^2+\sqrt{b-x^2}$$
Move $x^2$ to the other side, then square it again:
$$\left(\frac{(x^2-cx-2b)^2}{(c+x)^2}-x^2\right)^2=b-x^2$$
Multiply both sides with $(c+x)^4$ and you get a polymonial equation.

Comment: I'm not sure this has made much progress in actually solving the system, unless you can suggest a way to solve the resulting eighth-order polynomial?

Comment: Maybe you can simplify it for given $b$ and $c$, but otherwise I would go with a numerical solution. That's of course assuming that you solved correctly the system of equations :)

Comment: there's a possibility I didn't, so I have provided the system if you're feeling like solving some nonlinear systems

Comment: If you think about a geometrical interpretation of your initial equations, you have a cylinder parallel to the $x_3$ axis intersecting with a cylinder parallel to the $x_1$ axis, and then with a hyperboloid. Not fun :(